# Diagnosing incorrect indent in caption of code using listings package

Tags: listings, indentation

I am using the listings package to insert code into my document, using code from a [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/742069/5560474).

In my document, the caption is shifted right by about one tabstop (relative to page number):

[image]

I am using a customized LaTeX document class ([`MastersDoctoralThesis`](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis)), which I suspect is the issue.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,english,singlespacing]{MastersDoctoralThesis}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\textwidth}{#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white}

\begin{document}

Here is some code.

\begin{lstlisting}[label=some-code,caption={Some Code},language=python]
def prioritize():

    while True:

        if ( SOC <= 20 ):
            toggleRelay( relayHigh, 'off' )

\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: your MWE can use that class (it's generally known (notorious one might say:-) so it should be easy to make a MWE, just start from a copy of the document and delete everything except that float and then delete any package not needed for the example.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle done... in writing my thesis I've learned a tremendous amount about LaTeX, and gradually realized I should not have used this class. But this code is going in the final section of the final appendix, so a bit late to change it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some weird interaction which I could debug (if I really had to:-) , but the log tells you that it is 106pt too wide so this works

```
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\hspace*{-53pt}\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\textwidth}{#1#2#3}}\hspace*{-53pt}}
```

[image]

Comment: If you are interested why this indentation occurs, see the other answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

The template puts a margin to all captions. What you want is to remove that margin for listings captions. Or all captions if you like. Simply add `margin=0pt` while setting up the captions of your listings.

[image: lshaverListings]

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,english,singlespacing]{MastersDoctoralThesis}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{mwepage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings

\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\textwidth}{#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white,margin=0pt}

\begin{document}

\blindtext
\begin{figure}
    \caption{\blindtext}
\end{figure}

\begin{lstlisting}[label=some-code,caption={Some Wombat},language=python]
def prioritize():

while True:
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: yes this should get the tick really:-)